# Initializing a view controller as a initial view controller while using navigational controller ?[Objective-C]

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have tried using navigation view controller and setting up my screen as initial view controller using storyboard and it went well.

But when I did everything programmatically like below in my appDelegate.m file :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.


    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName: @"Main" bundle:nil];

    FirstViewController *firstVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstViewController"];


    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: firstVC];


    self.window =[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate] window];

    self.window.rootViewController = navController;

    return YES;
}
```

- My screen on the simulator is blank.
- But when I checked the `is initial view controller` for the respective view controller in the storyboard and run. This time, it worked, and the expected screen is displayed.

My question is, why should I check the `is initial view controller` in the storyboard when I am doing everything programmatically ?.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to create the first view controller yourself in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, you have to instantiate the `UIWindow`, too. But your assignment of `self.window` is just retrieving itself (lol) and does nothing. You'd generally do something like:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

When you use the "initial view controller" option, it takes care of all of this for you, which is why that works when you check that option.

And don't forget to `makeKeyAndVisible`:

```
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Thus:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *firstVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstViewController"];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: firstVC];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = navController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works. But I am getting a message "Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?
"

Comment: It sounds like you have specified the "Main interface" in the target settings. If you're instantiating the first scene, you shouldn't specify a storyboard in the "Main interface".

Comment: As you said, I tried not specifying the "Main interface" and when I run, this time, simulator shows me a blank screen. There is no message.

Comment: Also do `makeKeyAndVisible`.